# Populating an array

Tags: c++, arrays, random

Can you help me with a problem on populating an array of 5 circles with random numbers.
The random number would be the radius of the circles.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Array 2, below section is to populate the array with random radius
    float CircleArrayTwo [5]; // store the numbers
    const int NUM = 5; // Display 5 random numbers

    srand(time(NULL)); // seed the generator

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
    {
        CircleArrayTwo[i] = rand()%10;
    }

    cout << "Below is the radius each of the five circles in the second array. " <<   endl;
    cout << CircleArrayTwo << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Currently is output the following:

Below is the radius each of the five circles in the second array.
002CF878

Where am I going wrong?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: In C++ you should use `<ctime>` instead of `<time.h>` headers (and similarly for all other C standard headers). Also it's generally a bad practice to import entire namespaces into the global namespace, so don't use `using namespace std;` and just fully qualify your names (e.g., `std::cout` instead of just `cout`). Using `endl` both adds a newline and flushes the stream, which slows performance. Typically you don't need to flush so by default you just just use `'\n'` in place of `endl`. If you're using a C++11 compiler use the `<random>` library instead of `srand()` and `rand()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are printing the address of the first element of the array. 
You could loop over the array and print each element:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
{
    std::cout << CircleArrayTwo[i] << ", ";
}
std::cout << "\n";
```

Or, if you have C++11 support,

```
for (auto& x : CircleArrayTwo) {
   std::cout << x << ", ";
}    
std::cout << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you populated the array is correct, however you cannot print an array like that. You need to write a loop to output the values one by one.

Answer (score 0):

In C(and C++) arrays are almost equivalent to pointers to the beginning of memory location. So you're just outputting the adress of the first element; 
To output all elements introduce another loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) 
{
    cout << CircleArrayTwo[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`CircleArrayTwo` is a pointer.  When you print a pointer, it prints a memory address, like the one you provided.  In order to print the values of an array, you need to use the `[]` notation that you have for the insert.

You could loop over the values in the array and print each one:
    `for (int i = 0; i < NUM; ++i) { cout << CircleArrayTwo[i]  << endl; }`

Comment: CircleArrayTwo is not actually a pointer. Pointers and arrays are not the same thing. `cout << CircleArrayTwo` just happens to perform an implicit array to pointer conversion.